# como formatar variável com jquery mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera uso o plugin jQuery Mask Plugin v1.13.4

Tenho uma div onde eu informa um valor da seguinte forma:

```
$('#v_pg').text('PAGA R$ ' + valor_pago);
```

Uso Jquery para atualizar o valor dentro da div. Porém queria que ele fosse formatado pelo Mask da seguinte forma:

```
$('').mask('00.000.000,00', {
    reverse: true
});
```

Alguém sabe se tem como fazer isso? ou de tem outra forma?

Comment: Este plugin só vai funcionar com `inputs`...

Comment: @KennyRafael, o plugin funciona com divs também.

Comment: realmente o plugin funciona em div sim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua `div`, tente separar o conteúdo que você quer colocar máscara do texto estático.

Algo assim:

```
<div id="#v_pg">
   PAGA R$ <span class="valor_pago"></span>
</div>
```

Por fim, você pode colocar a máscara da seguinte forma:

```
$('.valor_pago').mask('00.000.000,00', {
    reverse: true
});
```

Deve funcionar.

Uma outra alternativa é usar o atributo `data-mask` no elemento. Eu particularmente nunca testei com elementos que não sejam `inputs` mas, teoricamente deveria funcionar:

```
<div id="#v_pg">
   PAGA R$ <span class="valor_pago" data-mask="00.000.000,00"></span>
</div>
```

Se tiver dúvidas, pode perguntar nos comentários.

Comment: Bom da sua primeira forma deu quase certo hahaha. Tenho 2 problemas. 1 quando o numero e negativo o mask ta convertendo para positivo, 2 preciso fazer com que meu jquery arredonde o número para apenas 2 casas decimais após a virgula . Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sobre positivo e negativo, não tenho certeza se a lib do Igor Escobar suporta padrões assim. Peço que dê uma olhadinha no repositório dele e veja se é possível suporter números negativos: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin.
Sobre 2 casas decimais, tente usar o método `toFixed()` do JS.
Exemplo: `valor_pago.toFixed(2);`.

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado